# How to animate update to values in BarSeries using QChart?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, bar-chart, qchart

I would like to be able to press a button and update the data shows in a Bar Series. The only way I have found to do this so far is by creating a new series and new bar sets. This has allowed me to create this:

[image: https://ibb.co/k3pRc4t]

I was wondering if anybody knew of a method that would allow the update to contain animation?
Something Like this:

[image: https://ibb.co/Lvg2md1]

Thanks :)

Comment: You could try setting `my_chart.setAnimationOptions(QtChart.QChart.SeriesAnimations)`. Values in an individual bar sets can be changed via `bar_set.replace(index, value)`.